# Unsupervised dedupe rules in the background?

Tags: contacts, cron-job, duplicate-contacts

It is my understanding that unsupervised dedupe rules take effect when one attempts to create a *new* contact, and they can also be run manually like any other rule. Can unsupervised deduplication be made to happen to *existing* contacts in the *background* (eg from cron)?

Edit: Or indeed, in the foreground but still basically automatic in terms of 'start it and wait for it to finish'?

Comment: You mean like what you do with running the automatic batch dedupe?

Comment: Aha, good idea. Maybe I'm being dumb.

Comment: Of course, another thing I've found now is that I can't add custom fields that are defined only for contact subtypes as dedupe criteria, but I can add custom fields that are defined for all contacts or for the relevant contact type.

Comment: Following my comment above, such conditions can be added in the dupeQuery hook: https://gist.github.com/futurefirst/a4e1d4346fa99b50cb8e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the third post here by Deepak.

http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=26491.0

I havn't tried it but it looks like scheduled mass merges are possible

```
Process batch merge (Daily)
API Entity: Job
API Action: process_batch_merge
```

Comment: This is a related question and may come in handy..
http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2567/is-there-any-documentation-for-safe-and-aggressive-merge-modes/2571#2571