# CiviCRM 5.13.1 API v3 Merge not working

Tags: api

The merge API was worked on 5.0 version but after upgrade to 5.13.1 the merge is Stopped working.

[image]

**Any help is very appreciate.**

Answer (score 1):

Normally contact merge process get skipped when there is something common in both contact and merge process unable to resolve it.

e.g. 
address conflicts (same address type on both contacts).

on actual merge contact UI, we have option to override the record or add additional record with same address type.

You need to pass Merge Mode in api call.
string mode: "safe" skips the merge if there are no conflicts. Does a force merge otherwise.

more info at [Is there any documentation for 'safe' and 'aggressive' merge modes?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2567/is-there-any-documentation-for-safe-and-aggressive-merge-modes)

Answer (score 0):

You have a 3rd party drupal module called tm_follow which something is trying to delete? The error doesn't seem related to merging. Check the [ConfigAndLog error log](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-are-the-configandlog-and-templates-c-directories) for more details about what might be trying to delete it, although it's not actually an error it's just a warning so there might not be anything there. But anyway the merge seems successful, there's just something going on with that module which you need to investigate.